# My javascript function not working, greyed out

Tags: javascript, html

I followed w3 schools guide on how to make a scroll back top top button in your html with javascript. When I put the javascript and html where they should be one of the javascript function didn't work. It got greyed out in vscode and in chrome console it says that the "function is not defined".

[This is how it looks in vscode:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJmmm.png)

I tried rewriteing the code in the html and js but with no luck. I also tried writeing a new function under the "topFunction" function and that also gets greyed out so I don't know whats seems to be the problem.

And this is the whole javascript with html:

https://jsfiddle.net/md5pf3hx/ a jsfiddle with the whole site

`<button onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn" title="Go to top">Top</button>`

```
  //Get the button:
  mybutton = document.getElementById("myBtn");

  // When the user scrolls down 20px from the top of the document, show the button
  window.onscroll = function () {
    scrollFunction();
  };

  function scrollFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
      mybutton.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      mybutton.style.display = "none";
    }
  }

  // When the user clicks on the button, scroll to the top of the document
  function topFunction() {
    document.body.scrollTop = 0; // For Safari
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0; // For Chrome, Firefox, IE and Opera
  }
```

Comment: what does your html look like? are you properly loading the JavaScript file? Does the script tag link match your directory?  A "Greyed-out" variable means youve declared something in some inner scope which you are not referencing.

Comment: If I paste your code into jsfiddle, it seems to work as expected..

Comment: @damonholden i put in a jsfiddle showing all the html js and css :)

Comment: It's a scope issue. Why are you defining functions in functions? move `scrollFunction` and `topFunction` outside of  `loadScript`

Comment: Oh, thanks i tried putting all of it outside before and the it didn't work at all but if i just put the functions outside then it worked as you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access `topFunction` because it's declared inside `loadScript` function.

You need to remove `loadScript` function

```js
const slider = document.querySelector(".slider");
const nextBtn = document.querySelector(".next-btn");
const prevBtn = document.querySelector(".prev-btn");
const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
const numberOfSlides = slides.length;
var slideNumber = 0;

//image slider next button
nextBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  slides.forEach((slide) => {
    slide.classList.remove("active");
  });

  slideNumber++;

  if (slideNumber > numberOfSlides - 1) {
    slideNumber = 0;
  }

  slides[slideNumber].classList.add("active");
});

//image slider previous button
prevBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  slides.forEach((slide) => {
    slide.classList.remove("active");
  });

  slideNumber--;

  if (slideNumber < 0) {
    slideNumber = numberOfSlides - 1;
  }

  slides[slideNumber].classList.add("active");
});

//image slider autoplay
var playSlider;

var repeater = () => {
  playSlider = setInterval(function() {
    slides.forEach((slide) => {
      slide.classList.remove("active");
    });

    slideNumber++;

    if (slideNumber > numberOfSlides - 1) {
      slideNumber = 0;
    }

    slides[slideNumber].classList.add("active");
  }, 5000);
};
repeater();

//Get the button:
mybutton = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// When the user scrolls down 20px from the top of the document, show the button
window.onscroll = function() {
  scrollFunction();
};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
    mybutton.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    mybutton.style.display = "none";
  }
}

// When the user clicks on the button, scroll to the top of the document
function topFunction() {
  document.body.scrollTop = 0; // For Safari
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0; // For Chrome, Firefox, IE and Opera
}
```

If you want the script run after the page is loaded you can add `defer` parameter

```html
<script defer src="script/js.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're issue is you do not have `topFunction` defined in Global scope. To allow your HTML to have access to invoke `topFunction`, you can move it outside of the `loadScript` definition.

```
function loadScript {
  // ...
}

function topFunction() {
  document.body.scrollTop = 0; // For Safari
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0; // For Chrome, Firefox, IE and Opera
}
```

However, you should be using the built-in `defer` attribute of the HTML `<script>` element to execute JavaScript **after** your HTML has finished loading.

```
<script defer src="script/js.js"></script>
```

This way, you can remove the need for `load` event listeners and whole-script function wrappers:

```
const slider = document.querySelector(".slider");
const nextBtn = document.querySelector(".next-btn");
const prevBtn = document.querySelector(".prev-btn");
const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
const numberOfSlides = slides.length;
var slideNumber = 0;

//image slider next button
nextBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  slides.forEach((slide) => {
    slide.classList.remove("active");
  });

  slideNumber++;

  if (slideNumber > numberOfSlides - 1) {
    slideNumber = 0;
  }

  slides[slideNumber].classList.add("active");
});

//image slider previous button
prevBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  slides.forEach((slide) => {
    slide.classList.remove("active");
  });

  slideNumber--;

  if (slideNumber < 0) {
    slideNumber = numberOfSlides - 1;
  }

  slides[slideNumber].classList.add("active");
});

//image slider autoplay
var playSlider;

var repeater = () => {
  playSlider = setInterval(function() {
    slides.forEach((slide) => {
      slide.classList.remove("active");
    });

    slideNumber++;

    if (slideNumber > numberOfSlides - 1) {
      slideNumber = 0;
    }

    slides[slideNumber].classList.add("active");
  }, 5000);
};
repeater();

//Get the button:
mybutton = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// When the user scrolls down 20px from the top of the document, show the button
window.onscroll = function() {
  scrollFunction();
};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
    mybutton.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    mybutton.style.display = "none";
  }
}

// When the user clicks on the button, scroll to the top of the document
function topFunction() {
  console.log('running')
  document.body.scrollTop = 0; // For Safari
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0; // For Chrome, Firefox, IE and Opera
}
```

Hope this helps.